# I need to show checkboxlist as box below the textbox when user clicks or hover the textbox inside a gridview

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview, checkboxlist

I need to show checkboxlist as box below the textbox when user clicks or hover the textbox inside a gridview.Please help if you have faced similar issues

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? (Helpful links for asking better questions: [ask], [FAQ])

Answer (score 0):

add this in script

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
           $(document).ready(function () {
              $("#txtbox").click(function () {

                  $("#checkboxDiv").css("display", "block");
              });
          })
 </script>
```

Add this in html

```
<div>
    <input type="text" id="txtbox" name="txtbox"/>
</div>

<div style="display:none" id="checkboxDiv">
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">I have a bike<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car">I have a car 
</div>
```

Do not forgot to add jquary.min.js on your page

Comment: Thanks Raj for your reply. I have my textbox inside a gridview. On clicking the textbox, checkboxlist div should open as a box.

Comment: ok then you can use the same method just by setting "clientidmode=static" attribute of textbox...IN .NET